# What are some suitable switches for programming/typing?

Tags: keyboards

Is there any suggestion for which mechanical switches are suitable for programmers or heavy typists? I want keys that are responsive and 'satisfying' to press, ones that don't lend well to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Since good mechanical keyboards are relatively expensive and key preference is just a personal choice my suggestion is to purchase a mechanical key tester. This is a small keypad with several different kinds of switches in there. a cherry mx version with nine of their key types can already be found for around ten dollars.

Other brands also tend to have these kind of key switch testers, but in my experience the most basic feel tends to be similar, just the quality and some details in the feel are slightly different though close enough to make an educated guess based on their cherry counterpart.

Comment: This is definitely worth the money just to sample a dozen or so keys to see what they're all about. There are some really unique switches going around these days so some of the larger samplers with multiple brands are worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the keyboard with brown switches and they are very responsive and nice to do some coding on... If you want more feedback try the heavier browns! The brown switch is intermediate between blue and black switches. If you're going to type but also want to play games on a keyboard, the brown switch is generally heralded as the best choice. They provide tactile feedback, so you can "feel" and confirm each keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

As a programming student, I really like the Sharkoon skiller SKG5. The keystrokes are reported fast (for the gamers, but also for other people), it gives good feedback when a key is pressed, it has rgb (not really useful, but doesnt matter) and the marco keys are really useful for something like console.log(). Its also really cheap, for if you are on a tight buget (I bought mine for 40 euros).

I like the heavy feel of the switches, but I've heard that mechanical keyboards are lighter, if you are searching for that.